# Typescript casting problem on object with getters and setters

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

I have a problem with the following code. I think is a casting problem, but I can't figure it out how to solve it.

```
interface Code {
  code: string;
  expiration: number;
}

interface IActivationCode {
  [userId: string]: Code;
}
const activationCode: IActivationCode = {
  set userId(id: string) {
    this[id] = {
      code: Math.random()
        .toString(36)
        .substring(7),
      expiration: new Date().setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes() + 30)
    };
  },
  get userId() {
    return this.id;
  }
};
```

You can copy the code here to see the problem.
[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Comment: The typescirpt playground link actually doesn't work. The error, anyway, is that you are trying to cast a string to type "Code". You rinterface is explicitly defining the return type of `userId` to `Code`, while you're returning a `string` (and the setter accepts a string).

Answer (score 0):

```
    interface Code {
  code: string;
  expiration: number;
}

interface IActivationCode {
  [userId: string]: Code;
}
const activationCode: IActivationCode = {
  set userId(id: Code) {
     id = {
      code: Math.random()
        .toString(36)
        .substring(7),
      expiration: new Date().setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes() + 30)
    };
  },
  get userId() {
    return this.id;
  }
};
```

changing the type of userId will remove error from code but i am still confused what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `id` and `this[id]` are far different. In your example, `this.id` will always be undefined because it's not assigned in the setter. If you try to assign it, however, it will throw an error, because you cannot assign an object property with `Code` type.

Comment: If I run `activationCode.userId = "myId";` I will get something like this: 
`{  myId: { code: 'vwurul', expiration: 1551775465464 } }`

I want to generated based on a user id a random string which is an activation key and an expiration date for that key